# IAR linker does not recognize .a library

Tags: linker, arm, iar, .a, stm32f4discovery

I am developing an application for ST's STM32F4-Discovery development kit with the ARM Cortex-M4F core.

I am using FreeRTOS in my application, which is intended to use the board's microphone and loudspeaker output.

I am trying to use ST's audio playback and record demo as an example for setting up the I2S interface for the mic. But I am having a real hard time with the PDM filter library of this example. This library is provided as a `.a` file and when I try to copy it into my project I get this message during linking:

> Fatal Error[Li004]: file
>   "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\FreeRTOSV7.3.0\FreeRTOS\Demo\CORTEX_M4F_STM32F407ZG-SK\libPDMFilter_IAR.a"
>   is not an object or archive file

I tried messing with the linker options and saying to manually add this library. But with no results.
Does anyone knows how to link a `.a` library in IAR?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the linker is complaining about the .a file not being a library it means that EWARM is passing the .a file to the linker, so tinkering with linker options will probably not work. I would rather suspect that your .a file is corrupt in some way. If you open your .a file in an editor, it should start with the string `!<arch>`.